# Add "edit article" button in joomla template

Tags: php, joomla

I created my own template for Joomla 3.0.

I'd like to display an edit button on any page (as the default template does) for every users with the right permission in order but I can't figure out how to enable it.

Any idea ?

**Edit :**

I tried to add this on my template index :

```
<?php if ($this->user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_content.article.'.$this->item->id)) : ?>
<li class="edit-icon"><?php echo JHtml::_('icon.edit', $this->item, $params); ?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but I got the following error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function authorise() on a non-object
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried !! and Stack overflow it's not for ideas.

Comment: <?php if ($this->user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_content.article.'.$this->item->id)) : ?> <li class="edit-icon"><?php echo JHtml::_('icon.edit', $this->item, $params); ?></li><?php endif; ?> I tried to add this but I got the following error : Fatal error: Call to a member function authorise() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't recognize the `User` object.
You have to declare the `User` object properly:

So your code should start with:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
<?php if ($user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_content.article.'.$this->item->id)) : ?>
```